# regex to match abc = abc statement

Tags: regular-expressions

Use emacs-lisp, how to match the same variable assign statement?

for example:

below lines should be matched:

```
abc = abc
xyz = xyz
weeoof = weeoof
```

But below lines should not be matched:

```
abc = abd
xyz = zxy
weeoof = fwexxx
```

I am trying `re-search-forward` but don't know how to do it!

Comment: What do you really need to do? Regular expressions are not a good method for this - in fact, standard regexps *cannot* do this: you need some sort of extended regexps (one more reason *not* to use regexps).

Comment: @NickD Nobody's talking about the abstract mathematical concept of "regular expression", but about the similarly named "Emacs regexps", which has extra capabilities which make this not only possible, but easy too!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use back-references in the pattern, so you can search for:

```
^\(.+\) = \1
```

Note that `\(.+\) = \1` (unanchored) would also match `z = z` and `f = f` in the second set of lines.  You don't need to anchor to the start/end of the line to avoid this, but you do need some way to differentiate those cases.  You might use `\_<` or even just `\b` in place of the `^` but it obviously depends upon the use-case.

See also <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(elisp)Regexp Backslash`

Comment: Advocating the use of the rx macro: (rx (submatch word) "=" (backref 1))